# types of authentication in .net-windows and form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, iis

I have a login form where if i enter user id and password it will validate the user against the entry put on sql database.
In the web.config file i can see the authentication mentioned as windows authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

if windows authentication ,IIS is authorized to verify the credentials. 
but for my login page im verifying the credentials with sql server.
Then where the authentication mentioned in the config file works?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication mode = Forms will allow the integration of a database and a web page for the login form. See the following how to from Microsoft to set up a simple membership database provider.

For MVC with entity framework http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

For web forms 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: but im using windows authentication and verifying with sql server for credential validation.

Comment: So to clarify are you authenticating the user is a valid Windows user against a domain or do you require a username and password combination which you then verify against your database?

Comment: i will validate against my database.

Comment: In which case you are using Forms based authentication as the user is authenticated against a username and password stored in your database and not against the Windows Domain.  Mike's answer is the most relevant in this situation.

Comment: But in my web.config the authentication mode is windows.